# How to configure Glassfish 6 Server in Eclipse manually

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Hello I'm creating java web application with eclipse and glassfish since 6 years ago. After this years was updating the IDE and Server wasn't the harmful like today. With Jakarta (namespace) , now I lose my IDE and Server. It's great move about Jakarta but I'm wondering why eclipse foundation and Jakarta (that supported by eclipse) not integrated and I can't start fresh new Eclipse(Last Version) and Glassfish 6 without getting error! If someone can do it please share with me , maybe I'm too new! All I want is Download the eclipse , download Glassfish 6 and start programming so if that have configuration, I don't understand about it, please share it with me.

[Other my question about eclipse and Glassfish 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412368/glassfish-6-are-not-supported-in-eclipse-eclipse-support-for-glassfish-6)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering why eclipse foundation and Jakarta (that supported by eclipse) not integrated and I can't start fresh new Eclipse(Last Version) and Glassfish 6 without getting error!

Well ... the short answer is because of Oracle's legal department, and their past history of legal aggression.

As the [Wikipedia page for Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) states:

> "Java EE was maintained by Oracle under the Java Community Process. On September 12, 2017, Oracle Corporation announced that it would submit Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation. The Eclipse top-level project has been named Eclipse Enterprise for Java (EE4J). **The Eclipse Foundation was forced to change the name because Oracle owns the trademark for the name "Java" and renamed the Java EE platform to Jakarta EE.**"

Given Oracle's tendency to aggressively defend Java trademarks, copyrights and so on, the Jakarta EE specification committee decided that the wisest (and most future proof) course of action was to do a Big Bang rename of all of the packages in Jakarta EE from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`.

Unfortunately, this has an impact on people transitioning from (legacy) Java EE to Jakarta EE 9 and later.

It has also resulted in a stack of extra work for the folks who maintain the Eclipse IDE.  Work takes time, especially when some of the work is done by volunteers.

References

- https://blog.hargrave.io/2019/05/jakarta-ee-and-package-renaming.html
- https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jakartaee-platform-dev/msg00029.html

---

> All I want is download the Eclipse, download Glassfish 6 and start programming so if that have configuration, I don't understand about it, please share it with me.

On the Eclipse Foundation's [Glassfish Downloads](https://glassfish.org/download) page there are resources on converting from Java EE to Jakarta EE.  Including a video.

Comment: we have jakarta ee but we don't have eclipse to write code! we can code but we don't have IDE! Just wait year(s) for develop by volunteers. I'm so depressed :( . thanks. @stephen-c